# Feature Convolution with Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, sequence, convolution

I was trying Keras and I am stuck doing the following. I have a list containing feature arrays and I need to convolute it with Keras. Feature array list is generated by the following code.

```python
features= []
for i in range(32):       # Contains 32 feature arrays
    x = np.random.randint(low=-1, high=1, size=16)  #Each feature arraysize = 16 
    features.append(x)
```

Convolution step I tried is as follows,

```python
conv = Sequential()
conv.add(Convolution1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(16,1),
                activation='elu', use_bias=True))
conv.add(Dense(units=1))
conv.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
#conv.predict(features) is the way I tried but failed.
```

I need to get the convolved list for input feature list. How can I do that?

Comment: please post the error

Comment: Why convolved features with randomly  initialized weights?

Comment: Feature list contains spatial features (Above feature list is an example) of geographical coordinate sequence. I need to capture spatial dependencies in the sequence by convolving.

Comment: What problem do you face with predict()

Comment: `ValueError: Error when checking model : the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 32 arrays` and also model.predict() doesn't return a convolved matrix

Comment: For the error, Convert the features list into numpy array after you append everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it states in the [Keras Sequential Model documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/), when you pass the dimensions to your model, you should include the batch size. Intuitively, you assumed that Keras takes your entire data and feeds it in one batch, but this has to be stated explicitly, using the `None` keyword which is used when the number of instances in your input is not constant:

`conv.add(Convolution1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', use_bias=True, input_shape=(None,16)))`.

Next, as you are trying to feed your entire dataset in one batch, your **dataset dimensions** should include the batch size as the first dimension as such: `(1,32,16)`. This can be achieved by: `x = np.reshape(features, newshape=(1,32,16))`.

I recreated your code with those changes and it works.

Comment: Great.. Thanks for the help